# Expression required intellisense warning in javascript

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I want to initialize some javascript variables in an aspx page from class variables set during Page_Load()

If I do
var x = "<%= ValueOfX %>";

Its sets it as a string.

If howerver, I want to set a numeric js variable, or perhaps a boolean type and not a string I don't want quotes, so I do this
var x = <%= ValueOfX %>;

I get an intellisense warning of "expression required". This doesn't hurt anything of course, but it clutters up the warnng list. It also puts a small mark on the screen in VS2010. It used to put the squiggly in VS2008.

Any other suggestions on initalizing js variables?
Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var x = Number.parseInvariant('<%= ValueOfX %>');
```